# Error: Can not find symbol. Symbol : method charAt(int)

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ArrayUtilities {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }

  public static boolean linearSearch(int[] array, int target) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array.charAt(i) == target) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why it is not working. I looked around on the internet but most people seem to have mostly typing mistakes, I don't think I made any, if I did make a mistake I can't seem to spot it. Thanks in advance :)

The error the compiler is showing is:

```
Can not find symbol. Symbol= method charAt(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

change your if condition

```
if (array[i]==target)
```

`charAt(int value)` function is not for int array. It is for **strings**

Check here for [charAt()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can not call

```
charAt(int index)
```

method from an integer array. If you want to get array's i^th element, you can simply use

```
array[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

charAt(..) in a funcion defined for type as int

Hence change if condition as below,

```
 if (array[i]==target){
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to invoke the charAt method on array which is an int array, not a String. You need
    array[i]
instead of
    array.charAt(i)

Answer (score 0):

Method `charAt`is a method of **String** class. An int array (`int[]`) does not contain such method. That is why a compile error appears.